# Flot, angularjs and getting data to plot via http get

Tags: json, angularjs, flask

wowee....can't use flask to return a json object to plot a flot chart in angularjs.

Totally does not work.  I use the hard coded json...the chart shows.  Whats the deal with a get requests in angularjs?  I go to localhost:5000/datatest and I see my json object.  Yet angular will not plot a valid json object?

In  flask..

```
@app.route('/datatest')
def datatest():
    test1 = [[[0, 1], [1, 5], [2, 2]]]
    data = json.dumps(test1)
    resp = Response(data, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
    return resp
```

My Controller and Directive.

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope,$http) {

     $http.get('datatest').success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });


    //$scope.data = [[[0, 1], [1, 5], [2, 2]]];

});


App.directive('chart', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var data = scope[attrs.ngModel];
            $.plot(elem, data, {});
            elem.show();
        }
    };
});
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/lib/flot/controller.js"></script>
    <style type='text/css'>
       chart {
            display:none;
            width:400px;
            height:200px;
        }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div ng-app='App'>
        <div ng-controller='Ctrl'>
            <chart ng-model='data'></chart>
        </div>
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directive is calling `$plot` before `$http` finishes getting `data`.  Instead, you can watch the `data` array in your directive, and call `$plot` when it changes:

```
app.directive('chart', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('data', function() {
        if (scope.data.length > 0) {
          $.plot(elem, scope.data, {});
          elem.show();
        }
      })
    }
  };
});
```

html: `<chart data='data'></chart>`

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/7nx2Xf5i1OfLEkzMdwNm

Comment: why was <chart data='data'></chart> used instead of <chart ng-model='data'></chart>

Comment: preference.  the alternative with ng-model feels less natural to me: http://plnkr.co/edit/JSD6VWChVFGx9g5baeYj?p=preview